# How To count how many times is clicked one Row in a GridView

Tags: c#, gridview, dictionary, shopping-cart

Im develop a shopping cart and I need to count how many times is clicked one row in a gridview to get the sum for this item.

I tried to figure out how to do, and I tried with dictionary to get the key (row) and value (count), but I dont know how to modified the value of the dictionary.

```
static Dictionary <int, int> list = new Dictionary <int, int>();

protected void SelectedIndexChanged (object sender, EventArgs e)
{


  for(int i=0 ; i < 100 ; i++)
  {
     list.add(i,0);
  }

  foreach (var item in list)
  {
     if(item == gridview1.GridView1.SelectedRow.DataItemIndex)
        list.key[item] = newInt;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok. I think you need to initialize your list outside the event handler.

```
static Dictionary <int, int> list = new Dictionary <int, int>();

static YourClassName
{
  for(int i=0 ; i < 100 ; i++)
  {
     list.add(i,0);
  }
}

protected void SelectedIndexChanged (object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
  list.[gridview1.GridView1.SelectedRow.DataItemIndex]++;
}
```